# my computer got slower but I don't know why

Tags: performance, computer-building, overheating

I've been having an issue for more than a year now and I can't figure it out.
The issue is that, at first my computer started to crash sometimes when I was playing video games. Then, one day it crashed and it wouldn't restart. The computer was on, I could hear my GPU screaming loudly but my screen was black (as my keyboard/mouse which are supposed to be illuminated).

Someday, it worked again, then the issue came back a few days later. I tried to manipulate a bit the alimentation plug and it worked again. But the thing is that now, when I try to play a video game (like Paladins or Fortnite) the game is very slow (like 15 fps) and I don't know why because before all this issues happened I could play around 110-120 fps pretty easily (if I remember well).

All this happened after I changed a fan, maybe it could be the reason? Overall, I have 1 fan (the one I changed) + 2 on my GPU + 1 on my CPU.

Specs: CPU : AMD Ryzen 5 2600 GPU : AMD Radeon 590 Fatboy OC+ RAM : 2x8gb Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4 3000Mhz C15 SSD : SanDisk 240gb HDD : 1 Tera (I don't know which one it is exactly)

Here is a screenshot I took when I was on my game's menu:

[image: Here is a screenshot I took when I was on my game's menu]

I opened my computer multiple times to see if the cables where well plugged and to clean it. Maybe I need to change a component but I don't want to buy anything before I have good reasons to think I need to.

Comment: Sounds like a heating issue. Could be a broken fan or a lot of dust in the fan of either the CPU or more likely the GPU.

Comment: For high CPU issues, I'd suspect a bad driver or service process.  First, fire-up Sysinternals Process Monitor (ProcMon) to see what exactly your system is doing during those times of high CPU.  More advanced, grab [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/using-the-windows-performance-toolkit--wpt--with-wdf) (WPT) -- which is part of Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) -- and run the Windows Performance Record (WPR) to capture a trace, then run Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA) to view and debug the trace for kernel-mode issues.

Comment: Given the symptoms you describe, take it to a local shop to see if they can asses what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you all I'll try to do what you said and I will also clean the fans again.

Comment: Also check for malware, e.g., cryptominer.

Comment: So, I just checked and the temperature goes near 85 degrees Celcius (I stopped at 84 but it seems like it could go higher).

Comment: stress test the gpu

Answer (score 0):

I changed the thermal paste and it fixed my issue. Thank you